# Jenkins getting error java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed

Tags: jenkins, exception, illegalstateexception

I have a few Jenkins jobs, and all of them are failing with the following same error, and no more info.
I checked into some of the bug threads, but couldn't find anything

```
Started by user Kadamb
java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed
    at okio.RealBufferedSink.writeUtf8(RealBufferedSink.java:56)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.DiskLruCache.get(DiskLruCache.java:433)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Cache.get(Cache.java:184)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Cache$1.get(Cache.java:139)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:207)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:450)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:399)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHeaders(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:155)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:199)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getHeaderField(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:190)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getHeaderField(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.noteRateLimit(Requester.java:350)
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester._to(Requester.java:300)
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.to(Requester.java:239)
    at org.kohsuke.github.GitHub.checkApiUrlValidity(GitHub.java:734)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.Connector.checkApiUrlValidity(Connector.java:324)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.GitHubSCMSource.checkApiUrlValidity(GitHubSCMSource.java:1380)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.GitHubSCMSource.retrieve(GitHubSCMSource.java:1433)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMSource.fetch(SCMSource.java:583)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.SCMBinder.create(SCMBinder.java:95)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:303)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE
```

What could be causing this? Does anyone have any idea?

I am new to Jenkins, and any help would be appreciated

**Edit:**
After getting exhausted looking for the solutions, I just restarted the Jenkins-server and it resolved the issue.

Comment: This seems to be related to Windows environment cache issue as mentioned [here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-54046?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel). If your [GitHub Branch Source Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Branch+Source+Plugin) is not up-to-date, please update it and then check.

Comment: I tried disabling the cache from the script editor, but that didn't work. After trying various options, I restarted Jenkins and everything returned to normal.